# Problem with connect mysql databases of remote

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-workbench

I'm getting error with connect remote mysql database. Firstly;

1-) I use windows 10 machine and my remote server also windows 10 machine.

2-) My database at locale at remote windows machine with root.

I tried so many things but [image] and

ı took error picture [image]

Also I CREATE USER user but again ı have a problem. How can ı fixed and connect remote database

Please help me?

Comment: See binding - maybe simply remote connections are not allowed?

Comment: that has nothing to do with the user, the port is probably not open and that is a good thing, you should establish between both computer a vpn and only communicate over this. even then you must configure mysql to accept connections from remote, because by default it only accepts localhost

Comment: I can not find my configuration file of mysql at windows. ini folder or else doesnt create

Comment: yes you are right.But ı want to maybe open out just one database to my teammate.We also use vpn to connect remote machine. But how can ı configure and shared database info?

Comment: Check service starting command line - used .INI file must be specified in it (`--defaults-file=` option). Then look the command line and .INI file for `skip_networking` setting.

Comment: you find it `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`for other versions you need to change the digits ProgramData is a hidden folder

Comment: I found the .ini file, how to configure this file any suggest document share or link? Thanks